# Http авторизация

Tags: c#, http

Есть такая конструкция для получения веб контента

```
public string GetPageContent(string url)
{
  string userName = null;
  SecureString password = null;
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
  var retry = true;
  var needAuth = false;
  while (retry)
  {
    try
    {
      if (needAuth && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
      {
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password ?? new SecureString());
      }

      var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
      {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
      if (((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
      {
        var args = new HttpExchangerNeedAuthEventArgs();
        if (NeedAuth != null)
        {
          NeedAuth.Invoke(this, args);
          if (args.Cancel)
            throw new WebException("Ошибка авторизаций");
          userName = args.UserName;
          password = args.Password;
        }
        else
          throw new WebException("Ошибка авторизаций");
        needAuth = true;
      }
      else
        throw new WebException("Ошибка авторизаций");
    }
  }
  throw new WebException("Ошибка авторизаций");
}
```

Происходит следующее. Запрашивается страница по указанному Uri. Если возвращается ошибка авторизации, то генерируем событие "нужна авторизация" и используем его аргументы как логин и пароль. Авторизация в такой схеме не срабатывает (при том, что, логин и пароль верные).

А вот теперь самое интересное. Если я задам `request.Credentials` перед циклом `while`, то авторизация проходит. То есть, наверное, после неудачного `GetResponse` в `request` что то портится. Но что, я понять не могу.

**UPD:**

Добавил после создания реквеста строку

```
request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

не помогло :(

Comment: Зачем вы делаете `throw throw new WebException("Ошибка авторизаций");` внутри блока catch? Вы же при этом теряете реальную причину ошибки. Пишите просто `throw;`!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для завершенного запроса повторный вызов `GetResponse()` вернет сохраненный ответ. Вам надо формировать новый запрос внутри цикла.

Comment: А просто обновить текущий нельзя? Именно пересоздавать нужно?

Comment: @iRumba нельзя. Это объект со stateful-интерфейсом.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.

Comment: А не подскажете, как сохранить эти Credentials для последующего использования? А именно, чтобы после перезапуска приложения не требовалось снова вводить логин и пароль. CredentialCache не сериализуемый (